# Does react-native have shake function in Android?

Tags: animation, react-native, shake

Hi i'm currently learning react-native to use Android phone.
and i want to make starting animation for shaking phone. 
I found that thing in Ios but i couldn't find it in Android.
Is there any system for them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pull request contains support for Android.
https://github.com/jadsonlourenco/react-native-shake-event-ios/pull/2

Install this branch -

```
npm install --save react-native-shake-event@https://github.com/z-dev/react-native-shake-event-ios.git#android
```

Use the APIs mentioned in README
https://github.com/z-dev/react-native-shake-event-ios/tree/android